# iOS Swift - How do I respond to a banner notification?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, sprite-kit

My Sprite Kit game has trouble reacting to **banner** notifications. When the user gets an **alert** notification, the game pauses as intended thanks to `applicationWillResignActive`, which isn't called with **banner** notifications. When there is a **banner** notification, the projectiles in the game go straight through walls instead of being removed from their parent after making contact with the (thick) wall.

I've searched, but I can't find any function that I can use to pause the game when the user gets a **banner** notification. Anyone know of a function I can use?

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options basically

Pause the SKView in your ViewController

```
self.view?.paused = true
```

The problem here is that it will pause everything which makes it a bit trickier to add pauseMenus or other nodes after.

The better way is to create a worldNode (global)

```
let worldNode = SKNode()
```

add it to the scene

```
addChild(worldNode)
```

than add all your sprites that you need paused to that node

```
 worldNode.addChild(yourSprite)
```

and than finally when you want to pause the game you call

```
worldNode.paused = true
self.physicsWorld.speed = 0 // call this as well when paused and reset to 1 when resuming
```

This way you can still add pauseMenu nodes/sprites, labels and so on while your game is paused.

To do this when a notification is received I believe you need to use the delegates methods in a your app delegate such as this one

```
application:didReceiveLocalNotification
```

You can read more here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveLocalNotification:

Comment: I know, I already pause the game when I get an alert notification. I want to pause the game when I get a **banner** notification.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried `application:didReceiveLocalNotification` but it didn't work with a banner =/

Comment: Himhh, than maybe read the above link. It depends what notification you have. Maybe some other delegates methods

Comment: I just read through a bunch of it again, but still no luck. Maybe I'm blind, but I really can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: That sucks. I thought the above delegate is what you need.